# calculate the partial derivatives $∂_1f(x,y)$ and $∂_2f(x,y)$ in all points $(x,y)^T$ $∈ R^2$.

Tags: partial-derivative

Let $f : R^2 -> R$ given by $f(x,y)$ = $\sqrt{x^4+y^4}$

Show that $f$ is partially differentiable and calculate the partial derivatives
$∂_1f(x,y)$ and $∂_2f(x,y)$ in all points $(x,y)^T$ $∈ R^2$.

Attempt:

Let us first consider the case $x,y≠0$. Then $f$ is partially differentiable with respect to $x$ and $y$, because $f$ is a composition of partially differentiable functions.
The partial derivatives are:
$∂_1f(x,y)$ = $\frac{2x^3}{\sqrt{x^4+y^4}}$ and $∂_2f(x,y)$ = $\frac{2y^3}{\sqrt{x^4+y^4}}$.
So now i dont know how to go with the points $(0,0)$ and $(x,0)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\partial_{1} f(0,0)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt {h^4}}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2}{h}= \lim_{h \to 0}h=0.$$